# angularjs how to do setup ajax like jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax

how i do this code in Angular JS

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   complete: function (jqXHR) {
      var new_token = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('X-CSRF-Token');
      $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content', new_token);
   }
});
```

> i want set new token when i post with angular $http

Comment: Try this in configuration of your module: 
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-CSRF-TOKEN"] = "YOUR_TOKEN;

Comment: i did it , not working

Comment: my code  `var AH_App = angular.module('AH_App', [
    'AH_App.services',
    'AH_App.controller',
]).config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('interceptors');
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/javascript';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
});`

Comment: i need do like this
`$.ajaxSetup({
            complete: function (jqXHR) {
                var new_token = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('X-CSRF-Token');
                $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content', new_token);
            }
        });`

Comment: I think that @Madhan Varadhodiyil solution is for you.

Comment: not working , i need update $('meta[name="_token"]') attr every post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this should working:

Factory Definition:

```
myApp.factory('tokenInterceptorService', ['$q',
    function CsrfTokenInterceptorService($q) {

        var CSRF_TOKEN_HEADER = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN';

        var token;


        var service = {
            response: onSuccess,
            responseError: onFailure,
            request: onRequest,
        };

        return service;

        // Private functions.
        function onFailure(response) {
            if (response.status === 403) {
                //DO SOMETHING
            }

            return $q.reject(response);
        }

        function onRequest(config) {
            //SET TOKEN TO SEND
            config.headers[CSRF_TOKEN_HEADER] = token;


            return config;
        }

        function onSuccess(response) {
            //SET HERE NEW TOKEN FROM REQUEST RESPONSE
            var newToken = response.headers(CSRF_TOKEN_HEADER);


            if (newToken) {
                token = newToken;
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
]);
```

Configuration Definition:

```
.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('tokenInterceptorService');
});
```

Comment: can you write $http an example code for do method POST

Comment: $http.post('/someUrl', {key: value}).then(function(data){//handle here data});
So when you call:
in onRequest Method you will set at every call your header token
in onSuccess Method you will read response header (CSRF_TOKEN_HEADER) and update your token

Comment: can you edit your solutions with my this code

`factory("interceptors", [function () {
        return {
            'request': function (request) {
                if (request.beforeSend)
                    request.beforeSend(request);
                return request;
            },
            'response': function (response) {
                if (response.config.success)
                    response.config.success(response);
                return response;
            }
        };
    }]);`

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, can you explain please with some details?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [interceptors](https://thinkster.io/interceptors) to push the token for [http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) requests

```
//Assuming you've created an module,

app.config([ '$httpProvider',   function($httpProvider) {
 $httpProvider.interceptors.push('CSRFInterceptor');
}]);
app.service('CSRFInterceptor', [function() {
this.request = function(config) {
    config.headers['X-CSRF-Token']= getCSRFToken();
    return config;
};
}]);
```

Comment: what about function **getCSRFToken()**

Comment: If you're using cookie based CSRF token mechanism you can get it from cookie